# Do I have to specify System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server all the time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Server.Mappath and need to specify "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server." as the prefix. Can I not do this as an include rather than for each use of "server.". This is being used in a class rather than controller hence the need.

Controller code:

```
string strMapPath = Server.MapPath("~/XML/");
```

When in a class:

```
string strMapPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML/");
```

Also applies to use of session object:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MasterDocument"] = myDoc;
```

It would be nice if I could just do something like:

```
include System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
```

But not possible.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
public class YourClass
{
    public YourClass()
    {
        Server = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server;
    }

    protected HttpServerUtility Server
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public void SomeWork()
    {
        Server.MapPath("somepath");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a *using alias directive*;

```
using Server = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server;
```

This will then allow you to use that directly as in your controller code;

```
string strMapPath = Server.MapPath("~/XML/");
```

Comment: Thanks. However..... Just tried it, and I get an error : "System.Web.HttpContext.Current is a property but used used like a type". Thoughts???